# How to parse a List of objects from a web service?

Tags: android, list, parsing, web, service

I have a web service that returns a List of objects called "PiantaPersonale", how can i analyze each PiantaPersonale after the instruction :

SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); ?

After this instruction i would like to analyze the PiantaPersonale objects of the list through the "get/set" methods of the class PiantaPersonale. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect we know how a PiantaPersonale object is formed and how to operate with it?

Comment: I didn't write the code because the class "PiantaPersonale" is very simple, it is formed by some variables with the relative get/set methods, nothing else.

Comment: try `Retrofit` lib... It's automatic mapping with your object